# Deploy SAS job query

Tags: sas

When I deploloyed sas code in deployment directory I see .lst file.
The premise is to run this deployed code praller with different parameters.

Each time .lst file is created and running this code in the same time in not possible,because .lst file is in use.

Is it possible to not ceate .lst file with deployed code or change the name .lst file with each running parameters?

Answer (score 1):

At the SAS command line use option `-print <filename>` to specify a specific name.  For example:

let <sas> mean "c:\Program Files\SASHome\SASFoundation\9.4\sas.exe"

```
<sas> -nostatuswin -nosplash -batch -sysin program -print program-####.lst
```

During a SAS session, use `Proc PRINTTO PRINT=` to change where the listing will go.

```
...

proc printto print="c:\mylistings\program\%sysfunc(datetime(),b8601dt.).lst";
run;
...
```

Comment: Is this should be add in the code?

Comment: Use `-print` in startup command or `PRINTTO` in a program